# Save file as root after editing as non-root

Tags: linux, bash, vim, sudo

Ok so this happens to me all the time. There has to be a better solution. Let's say you do `vim /etc/somefile.conf` and then you do `i` but realize you are not `sudo` and you can't write. So then I lose my changes by doing `:q` then `sudo !!` and make my changes again. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
:w !sudo tee "%"
```

The `w !` takes the entire file and pipes it into a shell command. The shell command is `sudo tee` which runs `tee` as superuser. `%` is replaced with the current file name. Quotes needed for files that have either spaces or any other special characters in their names.

Comment: :w ! is very different than :w! Now I know. :)

Comment: and that is why i never use vim. And also thanks for putting me above 10,000 rep. :)

Comment: I have the following in my .vimrc for just this purpose: "cmap w!! w !sudo tee % > /dev/null"

Comment: @kejadlen - that's a great solution!

Comment: This doesn't work for files that have spaces in their names. The proper generic answer should be `:w !sudo tee "%"`.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the extent of your changes, it might be faster to save (`:w`) your file with a different name, and then use `sudo` and `cat` to overwrite the *content* of the original file:

`sudo sh -c 'cat changed > file'`

Note that both `cp` and `mv` will replace the original file and its attributes (ownership, permissions, ACLs) will be lost. **Do not use them** unless you know how to fix the permissions afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file elsewhere (like your home folder) and then `sudo mv` it to overwrite the original?

Comment: I'd suggest `cat changed > file` to preserve the original file attributes. `mv` for this is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: What would be the command to do this within vim, once you've already made your changes as a non-root user?

Answer (score 0):

*Save the changes as another file and the make the approrpiate replacement.*

Answer (score 0):

When vim starts up, the statusbar says `[readonly]`, and the first time you try to edit, it says `W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file` and pauses for a full second. This is enough warning for me to quit and say `sudoedit /etc/somefile.conf`.

You can enforce this with a plugin: [Make buffer modifiable state match file readonly state](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_buffer_modifiable_state_match_file_readonly_state).

Comment: Yes I realize that but that warning is not always consistent on every system. Some flavors of linux don't show the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I use zsh templates and function completion.

Specifically [this one](http://code.google.com/p/zsh-templates-osx/source/browse/trunk/Library/init/zsh/zshrc.d/local-functions/general/vim?r=154). If I don't have write permissions, it prompts for my sudo password and automatically runs "sudo vim"…amongst other things.

Comment: This is a good idea. However, there is a catch here - we don't always open files as separate files on command line. often files are opened from within `vim` using `:e` or from `(c)tags`. There the shell function will not help.

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
function! SaveAsSudo()
    let v=winsaveview()
    let a=system("stat -c \%a " .  shellescape(expand('%')))
    let a=substitute(a,"\n","","g")
    let a=substitute(a,"\r","","g")
    call system("sudo chmod 666 " . shellescape(expand('%')))
    w
    call system("sudo chmod " . a . " " . shellescape(expand('%')))
    call winrestview(v)
endfunction
```

I have mapped `<F2>` to `:w<CR>`. & `<F8>` to `:call SaveAsSudo()<CR>`

Only advantage this answer provides over the `sudo tee` option is: `vim` does not complain about unsaved buffer or file modified externally.

Comment: A nice race you have here. Of course it probably doesn't matter much on a personal machine.

Comment: Yes, I only intended to run it on my personal machine. :-)